# Freezing with new Plasma 5

Tags: plasma

I got some freezes with new Plasma on Kubuntu. Does it says that my hardware just gets a low standard or I can make it speed up / remove annoying freezing 1 second after any actions?

Comment: Need more information, what is your hardware ? What specific actions cause the freezing ? What Kubuntu version ?

Comment: And how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

From this [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338999) this issue can be fixed by running this command in a terminal

```
export KWIN_USE_BUFFER_AGE=0; kwin --replace &
```